# Testing input length

Tags: javascript, html

I want alert to pop if input letters length is equal to 0 but it is not working

```
<div class="rame">
    <input type=text placeholder="Name" style="position: relative; right:-750px" id="inp1">
    <input type=text placeholder="Name2" style="position: relative; right:-250px" id="inp2">
    <button onclick="check()">submit</button>
</div>

<script>
    function check() {
        var a = document.getElementById("inp1");
        var b = document.getElementById("inp2");
        if (a.length = 0) {
            alert("Hello World")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Obviously make sure popups are enabled in whatever browser used, and of course javascript itself.  Try making an unconditional alert, and see if that works

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. With getElementById you will get an ELEMENT
2. In pure JavaScript length is meant for strings
3. If you want to compare you have to use double =

I think you tried this:

```
<div class="rame">
        <input type=text placeholder="Name" style="position: relative; right:-750px" id="inp1">
        <input type=text placeholder="Name2" style="position: relative; right:-250px" id="inp2">
        <button onclick="check()">submit</button>
    </div>

    <script>
        function check() {
            var a = document.getElementById("inp1");
            var b = document.getElementById("inp2");
            if (a.value.length == 0) {
                alert("Hello World")
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You should call `if(a.value.length==0)`. Note the difference between `=` and `==`.

Comment: or even better to use joda notation. `if (0 == a.value.length) { ... }` and then you'll never face this kind of misspell error headache

Comment: @RomanBobrik yoda notation :-) Let's use postfix aritmetic operators then :-)

Comment: no kidding, it is useful thing to avoid misspelling in conditions. saved a lot of time for me